# Squash all your commits in one, before a pull request in github

Tags: git, github

I need to put all my commits in a single one called initial snapshot, in order to release it in a github Repo, I know that for doing this I follow [this](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html)

My first question is that I want to share it with a external repository and this say:

> A word of caution: Only do this on commits that haven’t been pushed an
>   external repository. If others have based work off of the commits that
>   you’re going to delete, plenty of conflicts can occur. Just don’t
>   rewrite your history if it’s been shared with others.

and what happens I want to put all my commits in a single one, how to do this:

I found also this:

```sh
# Switch to the master branch and make sure you are up to date.
git checkout master
git fetch # this may be necessary (depending on your git config) to receive updates on origin/master
git pull

# Merge the feature branch into the master branch.
git merge feature_branch

# Reset the master branch to origin's state.
git reset origin/master

# Git now considers all changes as unstaged changes.
# We can add these changes as one commit.
# Adding . will also add untracked files.
git add --all
git commit
```

but nothing happens:

```sh
$ git reset  origin/master
$ git add --all
$ git commit -m "initial snapshot"
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: What do you get from `git rev-parse master origin/master`?  It seems that before running `git reset` you may have discarded your work.  No worries if you have, as you can find it in the reflog (`git log -g`).

Comment: This is what I get: $ git rev-parse master origin/master
78c4e31d7f813a127603aa93d63eb2c9db8d7c47
78c4e31d7f813a127603aa93d63eb2c9db8d7c47

Comment: Okay, so master is back on origin/master.  And does `git diff` or `git diff --cached HEAD` show any changes in your tree or index?  If not, you may have to find the contents of your lost master with `git log -g`.

Comment: Since March 2016, you don't have to squash commits anymore: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36377634/6309

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is by using `rebase` command.

Imagine you have this repository:

```
$> git log --oneline
af28aeb Another test
a680317 Try something
d93792b Edit both files
f23cdbd Second commit add b
6f456bc First commit add a
```

So you have done some test with commits `af28aeb Another test` and `a680317 Try something`. We want to squash them after `d93792b Edit both files` to clean the repository.

To do that the command will be
`git rebase -i d93792b`

Where `-i` is to indicate to enter in interactive mode and `d93792b` is the commit hash where we want to absorbe the previous one.

***Note: in case you want to squash all your commits like the first one, you have to use `git rebase --root -i`***

That command will show you that:

```
pick a680317 Try something
pick af28aeb Another test

# Rebase d93792b..af28aeb onto d93792b (       2 TODO item(s))
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

You have to tell to rebase command what you want to do. In that case, I suggest you to reword the first commit and squash the second as follow:

```
reword a680317 Try something
squash af28aeb Another test

# Rebase d93792b..af28aeb onto d93792b (       2 TODO item(s))
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Then your text edit will be opened to set the new commit message.

```
Fix bug

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# Date:      Tue Jul 28 08:40:04 2015 +0200
#
# rebase in progress; onto d93792b
# You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on 'd93792b'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#       new file:   c
#
```

Now you have to `git commit --amend` and `git rebase --continue` to finish the process.

And your repository will show like this:

```
$> git log --oneline
5f98806 Fix bug
d93792b Edit both files
f23cdbd Second commit add b
6f456bc First commit add a
```